# JavaScript not working on embedded object in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have my index.html file, with an embedded object - which is another HTML file, called list.html.
I made a JavaScript function, to display 4 random strings, that would create list elements and inject them into the ul in list.html, like so:

The object in index.html:

```
<section class="second-part">
        <object id="test" type="text/html" data="list.html"></object>
</section>
```

Inside the body of list.html:

```
<section class="list-1">
        <ul class="password-1"></ul>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </section>
    
    <script src="list.js"></script>
```

My javascript:

```
let possibleChars = ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "&", "<", ">", "-"];

let password1 = document.getElementById("test").contentDocument.querySelector(".list-1");
let list1 = password1.querySelector(".password-1");

function generatePassword() {
    list1.innerHTML = ""; // resets previous passwords
    for (let b = 0; b < 4; b++) { // create 4 passwords
        let passwordToPut = ""; // resets the password
        for (let a = 0; a < 8; a++) { // defines password length (8) {
            let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleChars.length); //randomizes the index of possibleChars array
            passwordToPut += possibleChars[i]; // build the password thing that will be assigned to password
        } 
        let listElement = document.createElement("li"); // create an empty list element
        listElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(passwordToPut)); // for this list element, create a text node with password to put
        list1.appendChild(listElement); // add a list element to the ul with the class "password"
    }

}
```

The p element that says "hello" in list.html shows up, it's just that the ul and li elements do not.
[what shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJpew.png)

What exactly am I doing wrong? Am I embedding list.html properly?

Comment: Why are you using `object` here and not an `iframe` or make an AJAX call and place the results into your DOM?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript you wrote for the embedded object remains locally scoped to that object.

So when you access the `ul` element with class `password-1` from the `list.js` file sourced in `list.html`, the `document` you are referring to when you call

```
let password1 = document.getElementById("test").contentDocument.querySelector(".list-1");
```

is the `list.html` file. This means that your `list.js` file has no knowledge of the element with Id test.

So to fix this error, you need to change how you access the elements. I edited some element names for a clearer understanding.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<section class="second-part">
    <object type="text/html" data="list.html" alt="password generator"></object>
</section>
```

```
<!-- list.html -->
<section>
    <button onclick="generatePassword()">Generate Passwords From within embedded HTML</button>
    <ul id="passwords">
        <li>pas1</li>
    </ul>
</section>

<script src="list.js"></script>
```

```
<!-- list.js -->
var possibleChars = ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "&", "<", ">", "-"];

var passwordsUl = document.getElementById("passwords");

function generatePassword() {
    passwordsUl.innerHTML = ""; // resets previous passwords
    for (let b = 0; b < 4; b++) { // create 4 passwords
        let passwordToPut = ""; // resets the password
        for (let a = 0; a < 8; a++) { // defines password length (8) {
            let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleChars.length); //randomizes the index of possibleChars array
            passwordToPut += possibleChars[i]; // build the password thing that will be assigned to password
        } 
        let passwordLi = document.createElement("li"); // create an empty list element
        passwordLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(passwordToPut)); // for this list element, create a text node with password to put
        passwordsUl.appendChild(passwordLi); // add a list element to the ul with the class "password"
    }

}
```